# how to switch values in data frame using two power-based octaves in r

Tags: r

I have a data.frame contains only numerical variables (see below). I want to change the values based on two power-based octaves, i.e.,
"0 = 0; 1 = 1; 2:3 = 2; 4:7 = 3; 8:15 = 4; 16:31 = 5; 32:63 = 6; 64:127 = 7; else = 8"

Input:

```
#   V1    V2     V3
#1  0     900    3
#2  1     5      44
#3  3     2      55
#4  7     0      23
#5  15    33     399
#6  28    234    34
#7  99    100    61
#8  140   22     3
#9  190   9      0
```

Expected Output:

```
#   V1    V2     V3
#1  0     8      2
#2  1     3      6
#3  2     2      6
#4  3     0      5
#5  4     6      8
#6  5     8      6
#7  7     7      6
#8  8     5      2
#9  8     4      0
```

I tried the recode() function, but it can not apply to data.frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot know how did you try with `recode`, but this way using `apply(df, 1:2, fun)` may helps.

## Data

```
dummy <- read.table(text= "   V1    V2     V3
 0     900    3
 1     5      44
 3     2      55
 7     0      23
 15    33     399
 28    234    34
 99    100    61
 140   22     3
 190   9      0", header = T)
```

## Code

```
poww <- function(x) {
  if (x <= 0){
    0
  } else if (x < 128) {
    floor(log(x, base = 2))+1
  } else {
    8
  }
}

apply(dummy, 1:2, poww)

      V1 V2 V3
 [1,]  0  8  2
 [2,]  1  3  6
 [3,]  2  2  6
 [4,]  3  0  5
 [5,]  4  6  8
 [6,]  5  8  6
 [7,]  7  7  6
 [8,]  8  5  2
 [9,]  8  4  0
```

## Using `lapply` and `cut`

```
as.data.frame(sapply(dummy, function(x)cut(x, 
                                        breaks = c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 5.5, 10.5, 20.5, 50.5,Inf), 
                                        labels = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6)))
)

  V1 V2 V3
1  0  6  2
2  1  2  5
3  2  2  6
4  3  0  5
5  4  5  6
6  5  6  5
7  6  6  6
8  6  5  2
9  6  3  0
```

Comment: @www I made a mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! But I wonder further if I want to use the scaling looks like it:  "0 = 0; 
         1 = 1;
         2:5 = 2; 
         6:10 = 3; 
         11:20 = 4; 
         21:50 =5;
         else = 6". How should I modify the code?

Comment: @YuhaoZhao In that case, I think there's no way to make it simple using `log` or something, then need to define `poww` with lots of `if-else` statement....If there specific rules or just manual intervals?

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes, the problem is there is no specific rules to define the scaling.

Comment: I modify the code, but it seems not correct... 
poww <- function(x) {
  if (x <= 0){
    0
  } else if (x = 1) {
    1
  } else if (2<= x <=5){
    2
  } else if (6<= x <=10){
    3
  } else if (11<= x <=20){
    4
  } else if (21<= x <=50){
    5
  } else {
    8
  }
}

Comment: @YuhaoZhao As you see, in new case, using `if-else` statement is too complicated. I add another way using `cut` above. Please check it out :)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please test the function `replace_fun` carefully to see if the output is as expected.

```
replace_fun <- function(x, base = 2){
  # Take log on x + 1
  x2 <- log(x + 1, base = base)
  # Take the celing
  x3 <- ceiling(x2)
  # Replace number >= 8 to be 8
  x3[x3 >= 8] <- 8
  return(x3)
}

replace_fun(dat)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  0  8  2
# 2  1  3  6
# 3  2  2  6
# 4  3  0  5
# 5  4  6  8
# 6  5  8  6
# 7  7  7  6
# 8  8  5  2
# 9  8  4  0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   V1    V2     V3
1  0     900    3
2  1     5      44
3  3     2      55
4  7     0      23
5  15    33     399
6  28    234    34
7  99    100    61
8  140   22     3
9  190   9      0", 
                  header = TRUE)
```